# Redshift Copy and Unload Security

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc

I have my Redshift cluster sitting in a private subnet, which is completely locked down. I want to run `COPY` and `UNLOAD` commands in Redshift, which will interact with an S3 bucket. I get that I will want to use a VPC endpoint to attach the S3 bucket, but I see nothing in the documentation showing how to open the correct ports to the correct IP ranges to allow `COPY` and `UNLOAD` to happen, and the only way I could get it to work for now is to keep Inbound and Outbound Network ACLs and Security Groups wide open. I'm not comfortable running this in production, and there must be a better way to secure Redshift for these operations.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "secure Redshift for these operations"? Why are you wanting to use NACLs? Aren't Security Groups sufficient for your security needs?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I included NACLs in this simply because right now Redshift is the only resource on that subnet. You're right that security groups should be sufficient for locking it down. I'm still working on figuring out my NACL strategy. The issue with Redshift and S3 would occur either way though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security Groups are sufficient for protecting an Amazon Redshift cluster.

NACLs are notoriously difficult to configure on resources due to the way that systems communicate. For example, an Amazon EC2 instance can send a request to Redshift on port 5439. The packet includes a *return address* that has a randomly selected port on the EC2 instance where the response should be sent. This is the way that computers handle responses when they send multiple requests to a system.

The downside is that you do not know which port will be required to send *back* the response. This is why you are experiencing problems configuring your NACL.

Security Groups, however, are *stateful* and automatically allow outbound responses back to the port specified in the original request. Just think of them as intelligent NACLs.

**Bottom line:** Use Security Groups, not NACLs.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. I'm confused on the use cases of NACLs then. Would it be considered good practice to keep them wide open on private subnets and restrict by Security Groups only, and on the public subnet implement NACLs as necessary?

Comment: Best practice is not to modify the NACLs at all. They can be used for unusual situations, such as creating a DMZ or blocking certain subnets from talking to each other -- especially when used with VPC Peering. In general, just don't touch them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that Redshift accesses S3 as a web service (like everything else does), then opening 443 outbound should be sufficient. Security groups don't block return traffic, so there's no need to leave inbound ports open (except 5439, of course, for specified sources).

But why are you concerned with blocking outbound traffic from Redshift? Normally you would only block outbound traffic if there was a concern that an uncontrolled program would run on a server. You may be over-thinking your network configuration.

Comment: That's what I thought it would do at first as well. It turns out Redshift `COPY` needs an Inbound port somewhere in the 30000-65535 range from some IP address. I didn't know which one though, so I had to leave it wide open for now. I feel like an IP-unrestricted rule for that big of a range is not a great way to do things. What do you think?

Comment: Those are "ephemeral ports" and are typically used as the client port when connecting to external resources (so would not be affected by security groups), but are also occasionally used when a service wants to accept inbound connections (such as JMX, or FTP in active mode). But there should be no reason that Redshift needs to open such a port when doing a `COPY`. Can you show the exact command that you're using, and describe how you're invoking it?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible cause for this is **Enhanced VPC Routing** https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-routing.html

If this is enabled, and your cluster doesn't have a public IP, and your VPC is locked down to outside traffic, then you will need to create a *VPC Endpoint* for S3 to keep all traffic internal to your VPC.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-working-with-endpoints.html